# TextBox behavior on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am returning to ASP.NET after a long hiatus, and am sure I'm doing something simple wrong, but I can't seem to sort it out. I have a page with a few controls (a few Literals and one TextBox), the values of which I am populating from a database query in Page_Load. When the value of the TextBox is changed, it correctly does a postback and fires the TextBox_TextChanged method, but it also seems to re-execute Page_Load, so the new value entered by the user is overwritten with the original value from the database. The only way I seem to be able to find to prevent this is to wrap the line that sets the control value in an if (!this.IsPostBack), which works fine, but I'm curious if there is a more elegant way to do this.

Thank you in advance,

Steve

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/

Comment: This is normal behaviour. `Page_Load` is run everty time. So use an `IsPostBack` check around the code you set the TextBox value.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean, "When the value of the TextBox is changed, it correctly does a postback and fires the TextBox_TextChanged method?" What causes the postback?

Beware that the TextChanged method doesn't work like JS (or similar) -- no check is done on each keystroke. It actually only fires on a full postback and the text is then checked for changes.

Otherwise, you've answered your own question by checking for a postback.

Comment: The TextChanged method triggers the postback as expected. I just wasn't sure that manually checking IsPostBack was the most elegant way to distinguish between initial page load and postback - though there might be another event that I was missing.